# Azure DevOps pipeline tasks: When to use them

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

so I came accross this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#environment-variables) (also available in screenshot below) and here I don't know why would you use a `task` (e.g. CmdLine) instead of using directly a `script` if they're both equivalent. What is the advantage in using tasks?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QHE2.png)

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think there *is* an advantage?

Comment: When you see two ways of doing things it's only natural to think if one way is more recommended than the other no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing up a few things.

**Script vs CmdLine**

As explained in the documentation and the screenshot, the 'script' task is a shortcut for the Command line task. Sot, it doesn't matter which one you use, they'll work the same.

**Script vs Task**

There are a lot of tasks available, that usually simplify a task or make it more readable. Every task, in the background, is just a script (either powershell or nodejs/javascript). So everything a task can do, can also be done in a script. However that does require a lot of scripting and so, a lot of effort. So it would be an advantage to use a task to save you a lot of time. However, sometimes, these tasks are also limited in options, so you still want to use a script to configure an option or do something that is not available in the task.

Usually I see a healthy mix of script tasks (even scripts are run by tasks) and other tasks in pipelines.

Please let me know if anything is still unclear for you.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, it's clear now!

Comment: @BahaAbrougui, please consider to mark the question as answered then.